# Where does Virtualbox store its data for writethrough disks?

Tags: virtualbox

I've got Virutalbox 1.6.2 on Ubuntu 8.04.

I've got an XP virtual machine with a single write through disk image.  The image file (WinXP.vmdk) itself is only 744B in size.  Somewhere there's several gigs worth of data for this machine, but I don't know where it is.  I've searched through my .VirtualBox folder and can find nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the fact that you have a vmdk, but are talking about VirtualBox, it must be assumed that the virtual disk was created by one of VMware's products, then imported into VirtualBox.  VirtualBox has been able to read VMware's vmdk format since, at least, version 1.6.2 (see: [changlog](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-1.6)), including the rawdisk/partition formats.

Do you have more than one partition on this machine?  Could the VMware XinXP-pt.vmdk be pointing to an actual physical partition on the HDD?

For example, there is documentation about how to set up raw virtual disks in WMware Workstation:
http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_disk_raw_install_linux.html

I'd run gparted, parted, or fdisk to look for additional partitions on the host drive.  Also, it might help you post the contents of the vmdk file.

Comment: Doh!  I set this thing up a year ago and completely forgot....  I do have a dedicated partition that had/has Windows XP on it, and I "virtualized" it.  Good call!

Answer (score 0):

.vmdk is a VMware disk. Unless you imported a VMware disk not sure what that is. Do you have any .vdi files those would the disk images created by VirtualBox.

You should be able to find it using the [Virtual Disk Manager](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#vdis)

Comment: No .vdi files anywhere.  In the Virtual Media Manager it lists the WinXP.vmdk file, and it's only a few bytes.  I just upgraded to 3.0.4 and the results are the same.

Comment: This is driving me nuts.  I'm trying to convert the vmdk to vdi, and basically can't because I can't find the actual data file.  The WinXP.vmdk file is text and points to a file called WinXP-pt.vmdk which is binary, but only 1MB in size.  This virtual disk should be at least 5GB.  I did a search for large files on the machine and turned up nothing.